# How to connect using WPA2-Enterprise on Android Devices?

Tags: wi-fi, wpa2

I am doing some product development for BYOD environment, so I require a wide variety of devices.  This one is causing me some issues with connectivity to the private network where I have to test.

The LG device with Android version 2.3.3 and upgraded firmware to whatever latest Sprint is supporting connects to the Wireless Access Point, but I get a 401 Unauthorized when access from a server on this private network. Meanwhile, the same configuration works with my iPad-1, an Android running Ice Cream, iPhones, Win Mobile, etc. using the same settings.

I am suspect that this device is too old to support WPA2-Enterprise but I cannot find any documentation, forum, etc. that supports any related issues.

I do not have access to the server to see why it is rejecting with the 401.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot/fix or officially lay claim of non-support?

Comment: My SGS with 2.2 has no problems with WPA Enterprise, though I believe 2.1 had issues; 2.3 should be fine.  Perhaps the Wi-Fi driver?  What encryption type and 802.11 version does the network use?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give the [WiFi Config Editor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Wifi-Config-Editor/com.oddrain.wifieditor) a try, which gives you much more configuration settings to play with:

[image: WiFi Config Editor] [image: WiFi Config Editor]
<sup>WiFi Config Editor (click images for larger variants)</sup>

I have not tried it (especially lacking an environment where I could really test it), but it might prove helpful, as you can adjust a lot of WiFi settings for a given AP here.

*Remark:* The app hasn't been updated for a long time, and obviously is no longer maintained. According to the comments, it's supposed to work fine up to Gingerbread (which would be fine for the device in question), but stopped working with ICS.

An alternative could be the [WiFi Advanced Config Editor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wifi-advanced-config-editor/org.marcus905.wifi.ace) (aka "WiFi Ace"), which explicitly states:

> Set WPA Enterprise and Personal parameters, like wpa_supplicant allows you to

[image: WiFi Ace]
<sup>WiFi Ace (click image for larger variant)</sup>

You might note the screenshot looks quite similar to the first of *WiFi Config Editor* above, so functionality might be quite similar as well. While this app was last updated 2012, it might have the same limitation: its developer couldn't test it on ICS (Android 4.x), but it should work fine on GB (Android 2.x). Comments give not much clue here (except that the app seems no longer to be maintained), but several reports from 2012/2013 stating success might indicate it's still doing its job with ICS and up.