# connecting to a wireless network that uses WPA2 enterprise encryption

Tags: wi-fi, encryption, wpa2

I'm trying to connect to a wireless internet I've got the user id and password for. The network uses WPA2 enterprise encryption and Cisco:Leap authentication.

How can I connect?

On my laptop I do this using a program by ThinkVantage technologies called Access Connections but on the Android built in wireless networks there aren't enough options.

Android version: 4.0.4 with JJHybrid custom rom (and rooted)

Comment: Seen this? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37241/how-to-connect-using-wpa2-enterprise-on-android-devices?rq=1 Particularly the last comment, what encryption, what wifi channel, is there mac filtering in place?

Answer (score 1):

The problem, in my experience, is that the vanilla Android UI doesn't give enough access to all the WiFi capabilities that the device possesses.

What I've done on my devices in the past, in situations where I needed to connect to an enterprise wifi is to remote into the device and change the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file manually. To do this though you'll need root access on the device.

The steps are as follows:

1. Make sure that you have the device connected to the computer and turn development mode on, with your device driver installed. You can find some of them on [Google's page](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers).
2. You'll need to have android-developer-bridge at hand, which comes with the android-sdk. You can get that [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).
3. In a terminal of your choice run the adb.exe file from the sdk with the following command: `adb.exe devices`. This will give you a print out of the devices that were detected. If not, check the steps above.
4. Now you'll need to pull the wpa_supplicant file to your computer's filesystem for modification, or you could do it through the terminal itself.
   Run `adb.exe pull /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf <The path you want to put the file on your computer>`.
5. Open up the file and modify it by adding a block with the following format (//is a comment and should not be placed in the document). You'll need to get the correct information from your network administrator:

   ```
       network={
          ssid="<Your network SSID>"
          scan_ssid=1 
          priority=1 //Higher priority makes this SSID take precedent over other SSID's
          mode=0
          key_mgmt= //For instance IEEE8021X 
          eap=  //For instance PEAP
          identity= "<Your username>"
          password="<Your password>"
          phase2="" //For instance auth=MSCHAPV2
       }
   ```
6. Save the file, turn off your phone's WiFi, and run `adb.exe push <Path of the file on your filesystem> /data/misc/wifi`
7. Now run `adb.exe shell`, and execute `chown system.wifi /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`
8. Turn the phone's WiFi back on, and hopefully this worked.

Another option is to try to use some of the WiFi management apps you can get on the Play market, but in my experience they haven't worked all that well.

Hope this helps you in some way.

-MrDresden